# Counting results of die rolls

Tags: java, simulation, dice

The algorithm bellow is meant to allow a user to roll a die as many times as he would like, then print how many times each side was rolled and how many rolls there were total.

```
    import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DieRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int roll;
        int totalRolls = 0;
        int roll1 = 0;
        int roll2 = 0;
        int roll3 = 0;
        int roll4 = 0;
        int roll5 = 0;
        int roll6 = 0;
        int numberOfRolls;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        System.out.println("How many times would you like to roll? ");
        numberOfRolls = scan.nextInt();

    for (int numberOfLoops = numberOfRolls; numberOfLoops>0; numberOfLoops--) {

        roll = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("your roll was: " + roll);

        switch (roll) {
            case 1:
                roll1 = roll1 + 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                roll2 = roll2 + 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                roll3 = roll3 + 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                roll4 = roll4 + 1;
                break;
            case 5:
                roll5 = roll5 + 1;
                break;
            case 6:
                roll6 = roll6 + 1;
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nyou rolled a 1: " + roll1);
        System.out.println("you rolled a 2: " + roll2);
        System.out.println("you rolled a 3: " + roll3);
        System.out.println("you rolled a 4: " + roll4);
        System.out.println("you rolled a 5: " + roll5);
        System.out.println("you rolled a 6: " + roll6);

        System.out.println("\nYou spun a total of : " + numberOfRolls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm can be simplified quite a bit. No need for `switch`-`case`. Just create an array (`faceCount`) with six slots and increment the appropriate slot. In other words:

```
roll = generator.nextInt(6);
faceCount[roll]++;
```

Then to print, iterate over `faceCount` and display the appropriate values (increment by one to adjust for array indexing).